# Search keyword from google to my site

Tags: search, keyword

If user search a particular keyword in google and google returns set of results with url. Now if user comes to my website after clicking any result, then how can I know that search keyword.

In bing and yahoo I am able to get this using "q" and "p" respectively. Like "http://www.bing.com/search?q=......" and  "http://in.search.yahoo.com/search......?p=......&.....".

But in google I am unable to find any parameters to get search keyword. I am using php.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
It is not possible to get the search string once you click on a search result.

---

if I search for stackoverflow.. this is what I get.. link not showing up properly in a comment..

so adding an answer.. you should be able to "?q=" as well for google

https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS524US524&oq=sta&aqs=chrome.3.69i60l3j69i59j69i57j69i65.2857j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: this is result showing in google. I want to know the next step, that's if any user click any link he/she goes to landing page of stackoverflow. In this landing page how can i get that search keyword. Does it make sense.

Comment: ok.. I get it.. thats not possible. It may be possible for the links via Adwords or Adsense but im not 100% sure on that

Comment: when user logged in google account, q parameter is not present but if not logged in q parameter shows the search keyword

Comment: @user2346003 even though it is consistent you cannot rely on those parameters as Google can change them whenever they want. Unless they have an API for it I wouldn't do it just by observation

Comment: I have another question. Can you please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082173/search-keyword-from-facebook-to-my-site